# SQL Query won't work when I use GetDate() but works when I don't use it

Tags: sql, date, datetime, time, sql-server-2019

I am trying to run this query, and it works totally fine if I run it like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
      dbo.Staging_Table
WHERE
      ((INCNumber != 'NULL') AND (CurrentStatus != 'MarkedForDeletion'))
```

But if I run it like this below, it doesn't work and the entry that should be returned isn't found.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
      dbo.Staging_Table
WHERE
      ((INCNumber != 'NULL') AND (CurrentStatus != 'MarkedForDeletion') AND (DateTimeNextCheck < GetDate()))
```

Note the addition of the `AND (DateTimeNextCheck < GetDate())` at the end.

The data is simply added in using GETDATE() so it's checking it against the same internal function that created the value and the column is set as DateTime property type.

Any help would be absolutely awesome, thanks. I am at a loss, and everyone online says I should be able to just do it as I am trying to.

Edit:
These are the values as requested to compare

```
SELECT
      [DateTimeLastCheck]
      ,[DateTimeNextCheck]
      ,GETDATE() AS 'GET Date Value'
FROM dbo.Staging_Table

 DateTimeLastCheck           DateTimeNextCheck           GET Date Value
 2020-12-11 22:39:00.000     2020-12-11 22:49:00.000     2020-12-11 23:20:35.370
```

Comment: (1) "doesn't work" isn't very informative.  (2) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (3) Sample data might help clarify the issue.

Comment: Add GETDATE() to the select list of your original query and show us (1) the value of GETDATE() and (2) the value of DateTimeNextCheck  in a row that should be  returned

Comment: @MartinSmith - added for you

Comment: Hmm, I agree that `2020-12-11 22:49:00.000` is less than `2020-12-11 23:15:45.150` so `DateTimeNextCheck < GetDate()` is true - did you check that row met the other criteria on `INCNumber` and `CurrentStatus `?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, it does meet the criteria as if I remove the 'AND (DateTimeNextCheck < GetDate())' from the query, it returns the row I want.

Comment: I truly have no idea why, or how it began to work, but it seems to work when it's running inside Orchestrator, but when I run it from SQL Server 2019, it just doesn't work.

Comment: What does that mean: "doesn't work"? Error? Output?

Comment: weird, what do you get with

SELECT
      ,[CurrentStatus]
      ,[INCNumber]
      ,[DateTimeLastCheck]
      ,[DateTimeNextCheck]
      ,GETDATE() AS 'GET Date Value'
FROM 
 dbo.Staging_Table
WHERE [DateTimeNextCheck] < GETDATE()